# Getting Ansible "Permission denied (publickey,password)" on multiple VMs

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I'm getting the following error when I try to run very simple playbook with the command "ansible-playbook site.yml -vvvv" against two Vagrant virtual machines but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

```
PLAY [Configure servers] **************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
<dev.db> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<dev.db> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<dev.db> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/flaugher/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 dev.db /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455651230.31-78392827258464 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455651230.31-78392827258464 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455651230.31-78392827258464'
fatal: [dev.db] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).
    while connecting to 192.168.2.102:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
<dev.web> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<dev.web> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<dev.web> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/flaugher/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 dev.web /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455651230.3-64535332497824 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455651230.3-64535332497824 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455651230.3-64535332497824'
fatal: [dev.web] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).
    while connecting to 192.168.2.101:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

TASK: [debug msg="hello, world!"] ********************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/smith/site.retry

dev.db                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
dev.web                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Here are how my VMs are configured:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.define "web" do |web|
        web.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
        web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.101"
        web.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 10122, id: "ssh"
        web.vm.host_name = "dev.web"
    end
    config.vm.define "db" do |db|
        db.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
        db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.102"
        db.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 10222, id: "ssh"
        db.vm.host_name = "dev.db"
    end
end
```

Here's my ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = inventory.ini
remote_user = vagrant
host_key_checking = False
# private_key_file = ???
```

Here is inventory.ini:

```
[development]
dev.web
dev.db
```

And the playbook site.yml:

```
- name: Configure servers
  hosts: development
  gather_facts: True
  vars:
    foo: "bar"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="hello, world!"
    - fail:
```

This seems like a SSH key file problem.  My first thought was since there's a private key file for each virtual server:

```
.vagrant/machines/web/virtualbox/private_key
.vagrant/machines/db/virtualbox/private_key
```

... perhaps I need to specify multiple private_key_file settings in my config file?  However, the Ansible documentation doesn't say this is possible.  I was also thinking that perhaps I need separate "[web]" and "[db]" groups in the config file so that I can specify separate key files, but again the Ansible documentation doesn't indicate this is a possibility.  The vagrant user on my local machine does have public and private keys in their ~vagrant/.ssh directory, all with the correct permissions.  I am able to SSH to each VM using the command "vagrant ssh [web | db]" and vagrant's home directory on each VM has an authorized_keys file in its ~/.ssh directory.  Can anyone see what I"m doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify keys at the inventory level with [`ansible_ssh_private_key_file`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

You can either do this with group_vars or host_vars depending on your use case. In your case you might just want to put them inline in your inventory file like this:

```
[development]
dev.web ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/.vagrant/machines/web/virtualbox/private_key
dev.db ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/.vagrant/machines/db/virtualbox/private_key
```

Comment: Thanks!  I believe what is happening here is that the private_key files you describe match up with the vagrant user's public keys which Vagrant puts in the ~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys file on each remote host.  SSH was failing and I was getting the "Permission denied" error because Ansible couldn't locate the private key needed for authentication with each remote host.  An alternate solution is to forego using the vagrant account to run the playbook. Provision your account when Vagrant runs, put your public key in auth keys on the remote, create your sudoers file and set remote_user = you.